Error in docker container in qdrant client - ValueError: Unsupported embedding model but the same value is present as a valid model in the description
We are using the qdrant python client and setting the embedding model in the client object.
The error received is
    File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/qdrant_client/qdrant_fastembed.py", line 122, in set_model
    self._get_or_init_model(
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/qdrant_client/qdrant_fastembed.py", line 205, in _get_or_init_model
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unsupported embedding model: "BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5". Supported models: {'BAAI/bge-base-en': (768, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'BAAI/bge-base-en-v1.5': (768, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'BAAI/bge-large-en-v1.5': (1024, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'BAAI/bge-small-en': (384, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5': (384, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'BAAI/bge-small-zh-v1.5': (512, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2': (384, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'thenlper/gte-large': (1024, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'mixedbread-ai/mxbai-embed-large-v1': (1024, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'snowflake/snowflake-arctic-embed-xs': (384, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'snowflake/snowflake-arctic-embed-s': (384, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'snowflake/snowflake-arctic-embed-m': (768, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'snowflake/snowflake-arctic-embed-m-long': (768, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'snowflake/snowflake-arctic-embed-l': (1024, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'intfloat/multilingual-e5-large': (1024, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2': (768, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'Qdrant/clip-ViT-B-32-text': (512, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2': (384, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'jinaai/jina-embeddings-v2-base-en': (768, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'jinaai/jina-embeddings-v2-small-en': (512, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'jinaai/jina-embeddings-v2-base-de': (768, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'jinaai/jina-embeddings-v2-base-code': (768, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'nomic-ai/nomic-embed-text-v1.5': (768, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'nomic-ai/nomic-embed-text-v1.5-Q': (768, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>), 'nomic-ai/nomic-embed-text-v1': (768, <Distance.COSINE: 'Cosine'>)}

Two observations

The "invalid" model BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5 is also listed as a valid model in the error message
This error occurs only when running via docker container. On the host machine (linux or windows) we don't get this error.

Any suggestions on how to begin to diagnose this issue?

Original poster here, this got resolved, here is how.
Docker parses the env files in a specific way, so if you have ENVNAME="ENVVALUE" the double quotes get included in the value.
Changing this to ENVNAME=ENVVALUE solved the problem
